# Using the kubernetes client to access the openshift API

Tags: api, kubernetes, openshift

The kubernetes-go client provides a subset of the functionality that is present in the openshift API.

It would be desirable that programs running on kubernetes could easily run on openshift as well, so long as the APIs were compatible.

That being the case, can we then access the openshift API using a pure kubernetes client written in golang, or does openshift need to modify the client functionality (even for simple API post/watch operations).

Comment: In general you should be able to use ``kubectl``. You obviously can't use OpenShift resource object types.  The OpenShift RBAC model as it exists under OpenShift multitenant model will also apply, so you might hit situations where the roles for the account you are using may not allow you to do what you want.

Comment: So, i can use the kuberentes-go-client, on an openshift cluster?  I figured auth wouldnt be the same... ?

Comment: OpenShift is just an Kubernetes distro underneath with extra resource types and services added in. It uses the same ``~/.kube`` directory on your client machine for holding client session information.

Comment: Ok.  Oddly ive had issues with this in the past, might have been due to the client-go refactoring.  I'll try it agin.